# User option in Access to select unique filepath for Excel source data

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am working off of a [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930832/import-dynamic-and-static-ranges-from-excel-in-to-ms-access-that-do-not-start-at/15947191#15947191) created by @MattHall from 2011 to a question that I also shared about importing a dynamic range from Excel into Access.

Specific to that--though in general for future VBA's--my question is whether there is an additional way to be able to point to the Excel source file if it is moved without having to go into the VBA editor every time?

For my specific needs, I am trying to work on these Access and Excel files with others through a shared BOX that has a different file path for whoever is working on it.

USER 1 may be: C:\Users\USER1\Box Sync\filename.xlsx

USER 2 may be: C:\Users\USER2\Box Sync\filename.xlsx

...and so forth for any other users. I am curious how we can all work off this when the file path used in the VBA created and used by USER1 is not accessible by USER2? Could there be some code that allows for the every user to locate the file each time through their own filepath?

It would be a pain to do that but I also do not know a better option as we are not working off a shared server and this is unfortunately limited to Box share at the moment.

EDIT: If anyone could also suggest how to integrate their recommendation into the 'Dynamic Range' code in solution from @MattHall in the [linked Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930832/import-dynamic-and-static-ranges-from-excel-in-to-ms-access-that-do-not-start-at/15947191#15947191), that would particularly helpful to my request.

Comment: [GetOpenFilename](http://peltiertech.com/get-open-or-save-as-filename/)

Comment: you can also use `ENVIRON("username")` to get the `USER*n*`. So `sFile = "C;\Users\" & ENVIRON("username") & "\Box Sync\filnename.xlsx"`