# Excel vba - Convert dynamic range to static range then export to Access 2010 as new records

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, ado

UPDATE 4

Posted solution.

---

UPDATE 3

Finally managed to find a solution to my problem, will post the answer shortly within the next few days.

---

UPDATE 2!

Put updates at the top for better readability.

So apparently it's not possible to use a named range from excel directly in the vba code when exporting to access.

After doing some more research I found there is a way around this: changing the dynamic range to a static range first and then using the entirety of the string as a variable.

*However my current code down below says it cannot find the range even though I'm sure the syntax is correct, is this because I haven't set the reference to the excel file correctly?*

```
Sub ExportAccess()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strQuery As String

    myAddress = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Names("ExportData").RefersToRange.Address, "$", "")
    myAddress = "[GWU$" & myAddress & "]"

' [Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;DATABASE=C:\Users\Public\test.xls]    < unused code snippet

strQuery = "INSERT INTO Table1" & vbCrLf & _
"SELECT * FROM " & myAddress & ""

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With cn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "C:\Users\Public\Database.accdb"
.Open
End With

rs.Open strQuery, cn

cn.Close
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

UPDATE!

After racking my brain for a few hours and checking the links I posted for some much needed reference, I came up with the following:

```
Sub ExportAccess()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strQuery As String

strQuery = "INSERT INTO Table1" & vbCrLf & _
"SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Public\test.xls].ExportData"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
With cn

.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"
.Open
.Execute strQuery
End With

With cn
.Close
End With

End Sub
```

I haven't been able to test this yet (will do this first thing tomorrow)
However I'm worried about the following code snippets:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Public\test.xls].ExportData"
```

This should technically select the 'ExportData' range from the test worksheet based on a different question here on Stackoverflow, I'm just not 100% sure if it will work

```
.Open
.Execute strQuery
End With

With cn
.Close
End With
```

Will this actually perform the INSERT INTO? and is closing the the connection really required? (I'd assume so, just would like to know for sure)

Kind regards,

---

I've been trying to get what I have in my head working for a while now, but to be honest I don't have the required expertise right now. I'm still fairly new to programming so setting up my own variables and arrays that I can actually use is still very hard for me. 
Hopefully you can help me out.

**The situation:**
So in an Excel read-only file I basically have a 10 row by 14 column range where users put their own data into, I want to only export the rows that have actual data that was filled in by these users to an Access 2010 database.

**What I tried before:** At first I wanted as simple of a solution as possible, I tried doing this by connecting the Excel worksheet to the Access database and then by doing a SQL append query on the rows where data is NOT NULL. (checks if entries in last column are NOT NULL)

However since many people will use the file at the same time I feared that the Access database/Connection to the Excel worksheet might get confused and start doing things it wasn't supposed to. When I tried to Google find out whether this was actually a problem or not my search results came up empty, so I was unsure if I should continue in this direction and ultimately abandoned this solution.

**What I'm trying to do now:** Basically I figured that I could do the same thing in an Excel macro before exporting, setting up a named range (via name manager) and then cutting out the rows that have no data in them with a simple macro before appending the remaining rows in the named range to the access database.

There are a few examples of people that have tried to do the same after a few google searches (unfortunately I can't post more than 2 links OR post linkbu.ch links):

- [Search results](http://textuploader.com/d5m1t)

However all of these examples seem to use a static range, not a dynamic range. How do I insert a Range from the name manager in VBA code? If anyone has any ideas on a different solution that would also be appreciated.

Kind regards,
FSDT

---

Comment: Is your range from name manager dynamic? It sounds like it is static if you always have 10x14 cells.

Comment: Hey @Niclas thanks for asking, basically when I remove the excess rows that don't have any data in them, the range from the name manager changes.

I've included an example here: http://i.imgur.com/MUVvh8J.png

Comment: In this link you'll find an example of how to do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15947191/1042624

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right everyone, as stated before this is the solution I came up with after trial and error:

```
Sub ExportAccess()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strQuery As String
Dim dbFilepath As String
Dim xlFilepath As String

    dbFilepath = "C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"
    xlFilepath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    xlFilepath = "[Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=" & xlFilepath & ";IMEX=1]"

    myAddress = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Names("ExportData").RefersToRange.Address, "$", "")
    myAddress = "[Sheet1$" & myAddress & "]"
    myAddress = "" & xlFilepath & "." & myAddress & ""

 STRcn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & dbFilepath & ";"

 strQuery = "INSERT INTO Table1" & vbCrLf & _
"SELECT * FROM " & myAddress & ""

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open STRcn
cn.Execute strQuery
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the macro recorder. Simply turn it on and manually go through the steps to export your named range. Then look at the VBA code you generated. The macro recorder is the greatest tool ever bestowed upon mankind. Try it, you'll like it.

Comment: Thank you, I already use the macro recorder for 95% of my work but unfortunately I'm unable to use it for this particular problem